# Select next item from combobox and click on a button Excel VBA

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

Have a combobox & command button placed on excel sheet. Combobox will have some items listed, say it have 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. When the combobox is loaded for the first time, by default first value ie 1 will be selected.

Now using a VBA macro, I want to select next value from the combobox list (ie 2) and click on the command button.

I googled this but unfortunately, not getting what I am expecting.

Here is what I have so far, but it dont do what I am expecting (Explained above): Getting an error message as Object doesn't support this property or method on line `If Worksheets("QC Update").ComboBox1.SelectedIndex < ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then`

```
Sub Select_Next_Items() 
  If IsEmpty(Range("A9").Value) = True Then 
    If Worksheets("QC Update").ComboBox1.SelectedIndex < ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then 
      ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0 ' select first Item in listbox 
      ComboBox1.ListIndex = ComboBox1.ListCount - 1 ' selects last item 
      Set ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = Worksheets("QC Update").ComboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1 
      Set ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 
    End If     
  End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You must show us some effort; kindly refer to [ask]

Comment: try the oleobjects object from the worksheet class

Comment: What does it do? do you get any error? please edit your question, don't use comments.

Answer (score 3):

hope you guys don't feel offended here, as I have a more clearer and a more straight forward answer.

```
ComboBox1.ListIndex = ComboBox1.ListIndex +1
```

Here is a more complete ones. We have to take into account when it is at the end of the list therefore

```
If ComboBox1.ListIndex = ComboBox1.ListCount -1 Then
   ComboBox1.ListIndex =1 

Else
   ComboBox1.ListIndex = ComboBox1.ListIndex +1
```

I hope my reply is helpful to most of you especially those who are new to Vba and need to use it urgently.

This is simple to understand if you have solid background on programming in C++ / java

Comment: FYI:  This won't work with the Access combo box because the `.ListIndex` property is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is your intention.

```
Sub Select_Next_Item()
    ' 07 Apr 2017

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Cbx As OLEObject
    Dim Ix As Integer

    Set Ws = Worksheets("QC Update")
    If IsEmpty(Ws.Range("A9").Value) = True Then
        Set Cbx = Ws.OLEObjects("ComboBox1")
        With Cbx.Object
            Ix = .ListIndex + 1
            If Ix = .ListCount Then Ix = 0
            If .ListCount Then .ListIndex = Ix
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

If the cell A9 is found empty, the code will look at the "ComboBox1" (and will crash if it isn't found on the same, specified worksheet). It will change the selection in that combobox to the next value in the list. But if it was already at the last list item it will select the first, and if there are no list items in the combobox it will do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I just modified the worksheet name to my worksheet name and tried to run it. It gives me an error as Subscript out of range on line `Set Ws = Worksheets("Update_QC.xlsm")`

Comment: "Update_QC.xlsm" looks like a file name. Ws must be a worksheet. it is better to use a real name, but for your initial tests you can just set the code to `Set Ws = ActiveSheet`

Answer (score 0):

Finally this issues is resolved with below code,

```
Set Cbx = Worksheets("QC Update").OLEObjects("ComboBox1")
        With Cbx.Object
            Ix = .ListIndex + 1
            If Ix = .ListCount Then Ix = 0
            If .ListCount Then .ListIndex = Ix
        End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I share my simple solution

```
    Try
        ComboBoxDireccion.SelectedIndex = ComboBoxDireccion.SelectedIndex + 1
    Catch ex As Exception
        ComboBoxDireccion.SelectedIndex = 0
    End Try
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.